# How to split string after last appearance of a certain character

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping

I have this URL

```
https://i.nhentai.net/galleries/1545079/1.jpg
```

And I need to delete everything after the last "/", preferably leaving the "/" in the string just deleting "1.jpg". I couldn't find any answers on the web, this is my last resort.

Comment: hint rfind and then google for substring in python

Comment: +rep for the *interesting* link content

Comment: I checked it after reading your comment xD @Daneolog

Comment: it's one of my favourite hentais tbh

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. use string split
2. re-join using '/' in between splits

```
URL = https://i.nhentai.net/galleries/1545079/1.jpg

# considering https:// as every start
URL = URL[8:]

# splits and excludes last item
new_url = URL.split('/')[:-1]

# re-joins the url
new_url = '/'.join(new_url)

# adds constant start
new_url = 'https://' + new_url
```

Answer (score 0):

Run a loop from last index to first and stop at the first occurence of '/'. Then build a new string up to that index.

```
x = "https://i.nhentai.net/galleries/1545079/1.jpg"

newStr = ""
for i in range(len(x) - 1, 0, -1):
    if x[i] == '/':
        newStr = x[0:i + 1] 
        break
```

Answer (score 0):

If its just for this specific URL you could do a slice:

```
>>> print('https://i.nhentai.net/galleries/1545079/1.jpg'[:-5])
https://i.nhentai.net/galleries/1545079/
```